# Show that any root $z$ of $z^4 + z + 3 = 0$ satisfies $|z| > 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that any root $z$ of $z^4 + z + 3 = 0$ satisfies $|z| > 1$ and that any root $z$ of $4z^4 + z + 1 = 0 $ satisfies $ |z| \le 1.$

What I've done so far:

$|z^4+z+3| \le |z|^4+|z|+3$.

If $0<|z|\le1, $ then $3< |z|^4+|z|+3 \le 5$.

How do I then complete the proof?

Comment: Hint: take norm and use triangle inequality.

Comment: @edm $|z^4+z+3| \le |z|^4+|z|+3$.

If $0<|z|\le1, $ then $3< |z|^4+|z|+3 \le 5$. How do I then complete the proof?

Comment: Do you know Rouché's theorem?

Comment: More hint: you would want to use [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Comment: @PhilippeMalot No

Comment: @PhilippeMalot It is an overkill. This problem could be a problem given in the first assignment of a complex analysis course, when complex differentiation is not introduced.

Comment: The first equation is equivalent to $z^4+z=-3$.

Comment: You want to show that $|z^4+z+3|>0$. That means you should try to find something _between_ $|z^4+z+3|$ and $0$. Finding something which is larger than $|z^4+z+3|$ doesn't help.

Comment: If $|z|\leqslant1$ then $|z^n+z^m|\leqslant|z|^n+|z|^m\leqslant2$ hence $|z^n+z^m|\ne3=|-3|$ hence...

Answer (score 5):

If $|z|\leq 1$ then $|z^4+z|= |z||z^3+1|\leq|z^3+1|\leq |z|^3+1\leq 1+1=2$.

So, if $|z|\leq 1$ then $|z^4+z|\leq 2$ and hence $z^4+z+3\neq 0$.

Comment: Or just $|z^4+z|\le|z|^4+1\le1+1=2.$

Comment: Directly $|z^4+z|\leq |z|^4+|z|\leq 2$. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments point to the simplest answer.  If $z^4+z+3=0$ then |z^4+z|=3.  But if $|z|\le 1$ then $|z^4+z|\le |z^4|+|z|=|z|^4+|z|\le 2$, a contradiction.